# Making sql insert statement safe

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm a newbie in the realm of SQL still, so I have a question about whether I'm using a safe practice.
I have a user table with a column for extra notes, which should be able to contain pretty much anything a person can type in. I'm taking care of (or I think I am) the single quotes in the notes field by doing

```
notes = notes.replace("'", "''");
```

Then, the query I will execute is put together like this:

```
String query = "INSERT into users (username, password, notes) VALUES('" + username + "' , '" + password + "' , '" + notes + "'";
```

Aside from the password not being encrypted, what else might I be missing here?  I'm not expecting that many hackers will even know of the existence of this software, but then again, nobody expects their code to be hacked.

Comment: If you state your platform people can link to the corresponding methods used to generate *parameterized queries* which take care of escaping values for you as well as generally being more flexible/readable.

Comment: Sorry, platform is Java, though I just needed to be introduced to the topic of parameterized queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use parameterised queries.

Using ASP.NET C#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableA (Username, Password, Notes) VALUES (@Username , @Password, @Notes)", Conn);
cmd.parameters.add("@Username",sqldbtype.nvarchar).value = username;
cmd.parameters.add("@Password",sqldbtype.nvarchar).value = password;
cmd.parameters.add("@Notes",sqldbtype.nvarchar).value = notes;
cmd.executenonquery();
```

Then you don't need to worry about single quotes, or SQL Injection.

Comment: plus - many servers will be able to cache a plan for a parameterized query and hence will perform quicker.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't mention my platform, sorry, but you gave me the answer I needed, even if it is a different platform.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I have no privilege to comment just yet, but what I can say will help is to utilize stored procedures, and to use object-oriented style of coding to use parameters.

You can also check this site out as it provides a lot of info on improving your security (which includes the fight against SQL injection): https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: +1 for mentioning stored procedures. Concatenating SQL commands is **very** dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Google for "prepared statements" - a secure way to execute queries with users input.